# Convert string to number for array to use?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, int

I'm practicing with arrays for c#. I have made this, but sadly it doesn't work at the end. I would like to have this:

for example, the user types "third". I want this to be converted to "2" in int, so the computer picks the third entered number. As I've coded it, it crashes now.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter 5 numbers of choice.");
Int32[] Names = new Int32[5];

Names[0] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Names[1] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Names[2] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Names[3] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Names[4] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("The number you typed third is " + Names[2]);
Console.Clear();

Console.WriteLine("Which number would you like the computer to remember? first, second, third etc.");


int Choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string ChosenNumber = (Console.ReadLine());
int first = 0;
int second = 1;
int third = 2;
int fourth = 3;
int fifth = 4;
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `it doesn't work at the end` <-- What exactly doesn't work? Please be specific. What's your expected input/output? What does your program produce instead?

Comment: It crashes down as you enter the value for int Choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); as you enter a string value and it can't be converted to int. Yet I want my program to automatically convert the string "third" to an int "2". Hope I have explained it well now

Comment: You could use an enumeration list, or a Dictionary for the conversion

Answer (score 1):

the quickest solution would probably be to add a `switch` statement to test the user input

```
Console.WriteLine("Which item to view");

switch(Console.ReadLine().ToLower())
{
    case "first":
       Console.WriteLine(Names[0]);
       break;
    case "second":
       //etc

    default: 
       Console.WriteLine("Not a valid entry");
       break;
}
```

Comment: Best to refactor into a translation function, which translates "third" to 2, then use it for `Console.WriteLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

This line doesn't work:

```
int Choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Why? Since .NET doesn't convert `first` to `1`. Just `"1"` to `1`.

Try this:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

// create an array of keywords
string[] choices = new string[] { "first", "second", "third" };

// get the index of the choice
int choice = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < choices.Length; i++)
{
    // match case insensitive
    if (string.Equals(choices[i], input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        choice = i; // set the index if we found a match
        break; // don't look any further
    }
}

// check for invalid input
if (choice == -1)
{
   // invalid input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this fails: `int Choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())`, because the user enters `third` but that string cannot be parsed to a numerical value, you could either use switch statements and take it as a case by case basis, or else, have a `Dictionary<string, int>` of strings and their respective numbers: `["FIRST", 1]`, `["SECOND", 2]`, etc. Then, you do something like so: `int chosenValue = Dictionary[Console.ReadLine().ToUpper()];`.

Answer (score 0):

It crashes at this line

```
int Choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

That's because converting from `string` to `int` doesn't work on a natural language words. It works on `string` type. So for instance you can convert a string `"3"` into an integer `3`. But you won't be able to do that for a word `"three"`.

In your case most obvious, yet tedious, solution would be to have a huge dictionary that will map `string`s to `int`s.

```
var myMappings = new Dictionary<string, int> 
{
    { "first", 0 },
    { "second", 1 },
    { "third", 2 },
    { "fourth", 3 },
    { "fifth", 4 },
}
```

Then you search for the user input in the dictionary.

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var result = myMappings[input]; // safer option is to check if the dictionary contains the key
```

But it's not the most elegant solution. Rather a brute force. Though in your case of five items it's not that difficult.

Other option, and the only reasonable one in case you would allow a bigger choice, would be to try to "guess" correct value. You would need to parse the string and create an algorithm that if the string contains word "twenty" and word "three" or "third" then it's 23. I'll leave implementation of this idea for you.